# Most common subpath in a collection of paths

Tags: algorithm

There is numerous literature on the Web for the longest common subsequence problem but I have a slightly different problem and was wondering if anyone knows of a fast algorithm.

Say, you have a collection of paths:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,3,4,9,10], [3,4,6,7], ...

We see that subpath [3,4] is the most common.

Know of a neat algorithm to find this? For my case there are tens of thousands of paths!

Comment: With this wording the most common subpath obviously will be a single edge, thus you just need to find the edge that appears a maximum number of times in the paths.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that a "path" has to encompass at least two elements, then the most common path will obviously have two elements (although there could also be a path with more than two elements that's equally common -- more on this later). So you can just iterate all the lists and count how often each pair of consecutive numbers appears in the different lists and remember those pairs that appear most often. This requires iterating each list once, which is the minimum amount you'd have to do in any case.

If you are interested in the *longest* most common path, then you can start the same way, finding the most common 2-segment-paths, but additionally to the counts, also record the position of each of those segments (e.g. `{(3,4): [2, 1, 0], ...}` in your example, the numbers in the list indicating the position of the segment in the different paths). Now, you can take all the most-common length-2-paths and see if for any of those, the next element is also the same for *all* the occurrences of that path. In this case you have a most-common length-3-path that is equally common as the prior length-2 path (it can not be *more* common, obviously). You can repeat this for length-4, length-5, etc. until it can no longer be expanded without making the path "less common". This part requires extra work of *n*k* for each expansion, with *n* being the number of candidates left and *k* how often those appear.

(This assumes that frequency beats length, i.e. if there is a length-2 path appearing three times, you prefer this over a length-3 path appearing twice. The same apprach can also be used for a different starting length, e.g. requiring at least length-3 paths, without changing the basic algorithm or the complexity.)

---

Here's a simple example implementation in Python to demonstrate the algorithm. This only goes up to length-3, but could easily be extended to length-4 and beyond with a loop. Also, it does not check any edge-cases (array-out-of-bounds etc.)

```py
# example data
data = [[1,2,  4,5,6,7,  9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,  8,9],
        [1,2,  4,5,6,7,8  ]]

# step one: count how often and where each pair appears
from collections import defaultdict
pairs = defaultdict(list)
for i, lst in enumerate(data):
    for k, pair in enumerate(zip(lst, lst[1:])):
        pairs[pair].append((i,k))

# step two: find most common pair and filter
most = max([len(lst) for lst in pairs.values()])
pairs = {k: v for k, v in pairs.items() if len(v) == most}
print(pairs)
# {(1, 2): [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], (4, 5): [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2)], (5, 6): [(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3)]}

# step three: expand pairs to triplets, triplets to quadruples, etc.
triples = [k + (data[v[0][0]][v[0][1]+2],) 
           for k, v in pairs.items() 
           if len(set(data[i][k+2] for (i,k) in v)) == 1]
print(triples)
# [(4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but to implement this efficiently is non-trivial and was seeking an efficient implementation of this problem. Yes, I was wanting the longest common subpath. An additional point to note: once determined that, say, (3,4) is the most common 1-segment then in searching for 2-segment, 3-segment, etc subpaths you would have to search in both directions; ie the segments before (3,4) and the segments after (3,4) since it can't be assumed that (3,4) is the starting subpath segment. Hence an efficient recursive or divide-conquer algorithm is not easy.

Comment: @user25029 Well, I think this is pretty efficient. You can't get better than linear (needed for the first pass to find the shortest-possible most-common subpaths), and then you only have to check to extend those. And you _can_ assume that `(3,4)` is the start, because if it wasn't, then the longer subpath would not be as common as the shorter one.

Comment: Say you had paths [1,3,4,5,7], [3,4,5], [6,3,4,5,8] and your initial search returned (4,5) as the most common 1 segment, which is equally shared between (3,4) and (4,5). It can't be assumed in this case that (4,5) is the starting segment.

Comment: @user25029 Typo. I meant "find the most common path**s**", not "path". You find all of them, and then try to expand them all on one direction. You need to find all, because if there is more than one most-common 1-segment path, then one might have an equally-common "extension" and another might not. I thought that part was clear.

Comment: I'll keep searching for an efficient algorithm written in pseudo code.

Comment: @user25029 I added an example implementation in Python. Maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post a solution in Python. It's greatly appreciated.